# How do I debug srcset with different dpr?

Tags: html, image, image-size

I've decided to change my site to use `srcset` for the images to account for low dpi screens. My site is images heavy, and the default 400x400 thumbnails look very nice on a hidpi screen. On a lodpi screen they're an overkill as the actual size of displayed image is 165x165. After the changes my `img` elements look more or less like this:

```html
<img class="img-rounded img-responsive" 
     src="/photos/tiny/gcu-01015.jpg" 
     srcset="/photos/tiny/gcu-01015.jpg 170w, /photos/thumb/gcu-01015.jpg 400w">
```

`/tiny/` images are 170x170 and `/thumb/` ones are 400x400. Sure enough, loading a page with these on a hidpi screens gives me 400x400 version. That shows the browser sees `srcset` and acts accordingly. I pull up the developer tools in Firefox, enable "Responsive Design Mode`, change the "screen" size to 300x700 with device pixel ratio of 1.0 and reload the page. It still uses the`/thumb/` version, even though the images on the page are now 120x120, and with dpr of 1.0 there's no point in pulling down 400x400 images.

[image: debug screenshot]

[Here's the page in question](https://srcset--gcu.netlify.com/varia/odaiba-unicorn/).

I've fiddled a bit with it but I couldn't find a good answer for the selection of the images. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here :|